# Is it possible to define resources with dependencies in Azure Pipelines YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is it possible to create a resource container that depends on another resource container and define that dependency through YAML? So something similar to `depends_on` in docker compose. For example, `kafka` is dependent on `zookeper` and I would like to use `kafka` as a service container without having to manually run zookeper and then run kafka, if I define it as a `service` for the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the containers are created in the order they are defined, so by specifying zookeper before kafka in the resource and in the service stanzas did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As of this time, however, `depends_on` is not supported in Azure DevOps pipeline.

Instead, you can use [Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#volumes).

> Volumes are useful for sharing data between services, or for persisting data between multiple runs of a job.
>
> You can specify volume mounts as an array of volumes. Volumes can either be named Docker volumes, anonymous Docker volumes, or bind mounts on the host.

Comment: It turns out that the containers are created in the order they are defined, so by specifying `zookeper` before `kafka` in the `resource` and in the `service` stanzas did the tricck. Not sure how volumes relate to the problem I was trying to solve